# How to pass optional date parameters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I think this should be simple, but I keep running into problems.
I simply want to return all data from a table that lies between a date range. But I want the date range to be optional.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ExistingPlacements_Get]
     @DateFrom  DATE = NULL,
     @DateTo    DATE = NULL
 AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT *
    FROM tblExistingPlacements
    WHERE
      CreatedDT > COALESCE(NULLIF(@DateFrom, ''), @DateFrom)
      AND
      CreatedDT < COALESCE(NULLIF(@DateTo, GETDATE()), @DateTo)
END
```

So, if no dates are passed in, we return the entire table.

If only the start date (DateFrom) is passed, we return rows > the start date and all the up to the current date.

If only the End date (DateTo) is passed then return all the rows < the End Date

And of course if both dates are passed, return all the rows inbetween those dates.

Am I going the wrong route with COALESCE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not do this. SQL will have to create **one** execution plan that works in *any* situation. As unituitive as it sounds, is better to have three separate queries:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ExistingPlacements_Get]
     @DateFrom  DATE = NULL,
     @DateTo    DATE = NULL
 AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (@DateFrom IS NULL and @DateTo IS NULL) 
       SELECT field, field, field
       FROM tblExistingPlacements
       WHERE CreatedDT < GETUTCDATE();
    ELSE IF (@DateFrom IS NULL)
       SELECT field, field, field
       FROM tblExistingPlacements
       WHERE CreatedDT < @dateTo;
    ELSE IF (@DateTo IS NULL)
       SELECT field, field, field
       FROM tblExistingPlacements
       WHERE CreatedDT BETWEEN @DateFrom AND GETUTCDATE();
    ELSE
       SELECT field, field, field
       FROM tblExistingPlacements
       WHERE CreatedDT BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo;
END
```

The wisdom of returning the entire table when no parameters are specified is highly questionable, but that is not the point. Besides:

- never use `*` in queries, always specify the projection list explicitly
- always use UTC times in the database

For a thorough discussion of this topic see [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html).

Comment: Thank you Remus.
Yes - I'd never actually use * but this was for ease of explaining my problem.

Answer (score 8):

Use `ISNULL(@parameter) OR (--your condition--)` instead of `COALESCE`:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT *
    FROM tblExistingPlacements
    WHERE
      ((@DateFrom IS NULL) OR CreatedDT > @DateFrom)
      AND
      ((@DateTo IS NULL) OR CreatedDT < @DateTo)
END
```

If parameter was not provided `ISNULL` return `TRUE`, so second part of `OR` won't matter.

Comment: Thanks Marcin,  

I'm getting the error:  "The ISNULL function requires 2 arguments"

Comment: @wotney Updated my answer. Check it now, please.

Comment: Using `((@param is null) or column <cmp> @param)` an anti-pattern which results in bad query plans.